# Powershell: What is the difference between char[] and String?

Tags: powershell

i found that the result $request.ContentType is difference by using char[] and String.

> $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest].create($URL)
>
> ```
> $request.ContentType = [char[]] "application/x-www-url-formurlened"
> $request.ContentType = "application/x-www-url-formurlened"
> ```

What is the different in the actual output to the server side, if I made a request like that using char[] and string?

it is so confusing...i guess it should be the same

thanks

Comment: I'm unclear--you have tried both? Do you see a difference? If so, what difference do you see?

Comment: yes there is difference, i found that using char[], the server side cannot recoginze the application/x-www-url-formurlended", but i don't think they should have difference , right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I figured out the issue. Check this out:

```
PS D:\> $foo = "bar"
PS D:\> $foo
bar
PS D:\> $faz = [string][char[]]"baz"
PS D:\> $faz
b a z
```

Powershell will cast your `char[]` into a `string`, since `HttpRequest.ContentType` is of type `string`, but for when Powershell converts arrays to strings it inserts a the value of the special variable `$OFS` between each element. The help for [about_special_variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx) has information on `$OFS` (and other things). The default for `$OFS` is a space which explains this behavior.

(Thanks to BartekB for pointing out $OFS in the comments.)

Comment: oh...reli thank...but do you know why such this happen? so confusing...and make me debug so long time

Comment: It's enough to know, that PowerShell uses $OFS special variable to change "$array" into "$array[0]$ofs$array[1]$ofs$array[2]...".
If you want to join arrays without any char - simply use unary join:
-join $array -> $array[0]$array[1]$array[2]